# Is [[no_unique_address]] on an unnamed anonymous union valid?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20

tl;dr: Is

```cpp
struct s {
  [[no_unique_address]] union {};
  [[no_unique_address]] union {};
};
```

valid? And if it is, should `sizeof(s) == 1`?

---

I've been messing around with various hacks to address https://github.com/woboq/verdigris/issues/31. In short, the problem is that I need to place a macro after a class function declaration with no intervening semicolon, and that confuses `clang-format`. For example, given:

```cpp
#define W_SIGNAL(name) { /* body */ } static void name##Helper() {}
```

This:

```cpp
class widget {
public:
  void sig1() W_SIGNAL(sig1)
  void sig2() W_SIGNAL(sig2)
  void sig3() W_SIGNAL(sig3)
private:
  int i1;
  int i2;
  int i3;
};
```

gets formatted to

```cpp
class widget {
public:
  void sig1() W_SIGNAL(sig1) void sig2() W_SIGNAL(sig2) void sig3()
      W_SIGNAL(sig3) private : int i1;
  int i2;
  int i3;
};
```

Unfortunately, `// clang-format off/on` doesn't quite solve the problem since `clang-format` appears to retain context from the area in which formatting was disabled. For example, this:

```cpp
class widget {
public:
// clang-format off
  void sig1() W_SIGNAL(sig1)
  void sig2() W_SIGNAL(sig2)
  void sig3() W_SIGNAL(sig3) 
// clang-format on
private:
  int i1;
  int i2;
  int i3;
};
```

Gets formatted to:

```cpp
class widget {
public:
  // clang-format off
  void sig1() W_SIGNAL(sig1)
  void sig2() W_SIGNAL(sig2)
  void sig3() W_SIGNAL(sig3)
      // clang-format on
      private : int i1;
  int i2;
  int i3;
};
```

`// clang-format on` needs to be placed after `int i1` to get the expected behavior, which is a bit unintuitive.

`clang-format` formats as expected if semicolons are added after `W_SIGNAL(<name>)`, but those semicolons trigger `-Wextra-semi` warnings. Extra semicolons are fairly harmless, so the warning could be disabled without much fuss, but for the sake of the question let's assume that I can't disable it.

Adding an unnamed anonymous union at the end of the macro definition allows ending semicolons to be added without triggering `-Wextra-semi`:

```cpp
#define W_SIGNAL(name) {} static void name##Helper() {} union {}
```

So this:

```cpp
class widget {
public:
  void sig1() W_SIGNAL(sig1);
  void sig2() W_SIGNAL(sig2);
  void sig3() W_SIGNAL(sig3);
private:
  int i1;
  int i2;
  int i3;
};
```

Gets formatted as expected, and does not trigger `-Wextra-semi`. Clang and MSVC do emit a different warning (`-Wmissing-declarations`/`C4408`, respectively), but those can be `_Pragma`'d away in the macro itself and made effectively invisible to the user.

The anonymous union, however, alters the size of the containing class, so `sizeof(widget) > 3 * sizeof(int))`. I was curious whether C++20's `[[no_unique_address]]` attribute could help here, since the unions were empty and could conceivably be folded together. When I [tried it](https://godbolt.org/z/W365vz7Ya), it turned out that Clang accepted the attribute and optimized as I expected, but GCC ignored the attribute and MSVC rejected it.

GCC:

```
<source>:1:66: warning: attribute ignored in declaration of 'union widget::<unnamed>' [-Wattributes]
    1 | #define W_SIGNAL(...) { /* body */ } [[no_unique_address]] union {}
      |                                                                  ^
<source>:3:15: note: in expansion of macro 'W_SIGNAL'
    3 |   void sig1() W_SIGNAL(sig1);
      |               ^~~~~~~~
<source>:1:66: note: attribute for 'union widget::<unnamed>' must follow the 'union' keyword
    1 | #define W_SIGNAL(...) { /* body */ } [[no_unique_address]] union {}
      |                                                                  ^
<source>:3:15: note: in expansion of macro 'W_SIGNAL'
    3 |   void sig1() W_SIGNAL(sig1);
      |   
<snip>
<source>:13:30: error: static assertion failed
   13 | static_assert(sizeof(widget) == 3 * sizeof(int));
      |               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

MSVC:

```
<source>(3): error C7545: attribute 'no_unique_address' can only be applied to a non-static data member that is not a bitfield
<source>(4): error C7545: attribute 'no_unique_address' can only be applied to a non-static data member that is not a bitfield
<source>(5): error C7545: attribute 'no_unique_address' can only be applied to a non-static data member that is not a bitfield
<source>(13): error C2607: static assertion failed
```

Giving the union a member name (e.g., `[[no_unique_address]] union {} W_MACRO_CONCAT(u, __LINE__)`) makes the code valid, with only MSVC emitting an error due to the `static_assert` failing. This, however, may pollute IDE/LSP autocompletion lists, which isn't ideal.

*So*, ignoring all the relatively trivial workarounds I dismissed for one reason or another, which compiler is correct here?

Comment: Would redefining the functions like `void sig1() { W_SIGNAL(sig1) }` (with an extra pair of curly brackets) help any?

Comment: This feels like tails wagging dogs...but if you have to have something to eat up the semicolon, how about a `static_assert(true)`?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm I don't think that would help, unfortunately; the [actual macro](https://github.com/woboq/verdigris/blob/b1a956a3b7427a822f22cda9d97318968d328aec/src/wobjectdefs.h#L863-L876) contains function definitions. Sorry for not being more specific with my example; I would have mentioned it had I thought of that solution.

Comment: @T.C. That's a brilliant idea! Wish I had thought of something that straightforwards. Completely obviates the need for the `[[no_unique_address]]` hack

Comment: `union {}` is not even an anonymous union, an anonymous union shall have _member-specification_.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer I'm admittedly not as well-versed with C++ as I would like, so it's not surprising I used the wrong term. What should I have called it instead, if it has a proper name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a *member-declaration* of the form

*attribute-specifier-seq*(opt) *decl-specifier-seq*(opt) *member-declarator-list*(opt) `;`

the *attribute-specifier-seq* appertains to the entities being declared, and is only allowed to appear when the *member-declarator-list* is present ([[class.mem.general]/14](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.mem#general-14)).

This implies that the form

```
[[no_unique_address]] union {};
```

is not allowed as a member declaration. There are no declarators in this declaration. `union {}` is a *decl-specifier-seq*.

Generally, an *attribute-specifier-seq* may appear after all *decl-specifier*s in a *decl-specifier-seq*, in which case it appertains to the *type* determined by the *decl-specifier-seq* in that declaration only ([[dcl.spec.general]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.spec#general-1)). If a new type is being defined by a *decl-specifier*, as with a `struct`, `class`, `union`, `enum`, `enum struct`, or `enum class` definition, then an *attribute-specifier-seq* may also appear after the aforementioned keyword sequences, and attaches to the type defined. Both of these cases would be ill-formed, because `[[no_unique_address]]` may only appertain to a non-static data member. The grammar of the C++ language provides no way to make `[[no_unique_address]]` appertain to the unnamed non-static data member defined by the anonymous union definition.

Even if this worked, it would certainly be an odd way of addressing your actual problem. My personal opinion is that the extra semicolon solution is better.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to dive through the C++ grammar! Quick question - would the grammar also forbid `[[no_unique_address]]` even if the union had a name (e.g., `[[no_unique_address]] union {} u`)? I'm still inexperienced at parsing Standardese, so I might have missed the right chain of productions.

Comment: @awksp In that case, it's allowed. You can either put `[[no_unique_address]]` at the beginning, or you can put it right after `u`. The effect is the same.

Comment: Ah, I think I see the right chain - *member-declarator-list* -> *member-declarator*, which has *identifier* in the fourth rule. Is that the right way to read this? And what's the colon after *attribute-specifier-seq* for? Don't recall seeing one in this kind of situation before.

Comment: @awksp The `:` is used to declare a bit-field

Comment: Ah, so the thing I picked up was specifically for bitfields. Thank you for taking the time to answer my further questions! I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

> Is [[no_unique_address]] on an unnamed anonymous union valid?

There appears to be no rule disallowing it.

> should sizeof(s) == 1?

It **can** be, but "should" is a bit too strong. It is implementation defined.

> [intro.object]
>
> An object has nonzero size if it ... Otherwise, if the object is a base class subobject ... Otherwise, the circumstances under which the object has zero size are implementation-defined.

---

As for the formatting, the union trick seems like a horrible hack. I recommend following:

```
void sig1() { W_SIGNAL(sig1) }
```

Given that the macro defines a body for the function, this also improves readability because it becomes obvious that a function is being defined.

Comment: "the union trick seems like a horrible hack": I 101% agree. In an actual codebase I'd probably pick a different solution, but I wanted to see how far I'd have to go to get something truly "invisible".

Comment: As for the suggested solution, it unfortunately wouldn't work with the [actual macro](https://github.com/woboq/verdigris/blob/b1a956a3b7427a822f22cda9d97318968d328aec/src/wobjectdefs.h#L863-L876) because it contains additional function definitions. I would have included such in the example if I had though of your proposed solution, so it's my fault for not being specific enough. Sorry!